# SharePoint 2013 connect to Outlook is grayed in my windows 8 Internet Explorer?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, internet-explorer, windows-8

I am using SharePoint 2013 my connect to Outlook button is grayed out when I open my page in windows 8 Internet explorer it is grayed out,
 but it is working fine with windows 7 Internet explorer also it is working with Google Chrome.
I don't know how to fix this issue with windows 8 Internet explorer?

Comment: It is only working with 32-bit version of IE, so start with verifying that

Comment: How to solve this issue

Comment: Have you verified that you are using 32-but IE? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

Comment: Also there is an issue related to Minimal Download Strategy. Sometimes you need to press F5 in order to make it enabled.

Comment: No I pressed many times F5 but it is not working

Comment: I am using 64-bit IE11, 32-bit Office 2013, and the button is enabled for me... but not for another computer with the same configuration.  This is _not_ simply a 32-bit issue.